# Rewrite website URL to remove query string variables question mark?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a current url that has query string variables. I'd like to remove them so that only the second part of the query string is visible.
From: `mysite.com/posts?post=45&tab=profile`
To:  `mysite.com/posts/45/profile`
Current `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+access/(\S*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/access/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ access/$1.php [L,NC]
```

SITEMAP

```
index.php
/access
    -dashboard.php
    -posts.php
    -account.php
```

This query string will always have parameter 1, but may or may not have parameter 2, depending on what they click on the scree.

Comment: Where does `posts.php` reside? Is it inside `access/` directory?

Comment: yes, i will update directory information in a minute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it like this:

```sh
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+access/(\S*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# 2 parameter rule
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/access/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ access/$1.php?post=$2&tab=$3 [QSA,L]

# 1 parameter rule
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/access/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ access/$1.php?post=$2 [QSA,L]

# php extension
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/access/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ access/$1.php [L,NC]

# php extension
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L,NC]
```

- Option `MultiViews` (see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/content-negotiation.html) is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs **before** `mod_rewrite` and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So if `/file` is the URL then Apache will serve `/file.html`.

Comment: hi again, i think it is working, have to change a few things on my javascript side to properly parse the URL now. but in php if I `echo $_GET['post'];` It prints out whatever number I use after the slash

Comment: I made a minor edit. If you use URL as `mysite.com/posts/45/profile` then it will give`$_GET['post']=45` and `$_GET['tab']=profile`. I believe this is what you want.

Comment: I was able to get it to work, thank you! I just have a couple questions. what does the `MultiViews` do in this situation? Also, for the php extension rule, is there a way to write it so that any php file has the extension removed? because if i make an ajax call to another folder i have to put the php extension. thanks!

Comment: I have modified `# php extension` rule to make it work for any folder. `Options -MultiViews` turns off content negotiation service. I have added an explanation in answer.

Comment: thank you, i tried your new solution which seems to work for some things. hah, now it is working for every file that is not in the `access` folder. all files inside the `access` folder do not work unless they have a querystring variable

Comment: wow you are the best! you have helped me more than anyone on this site. please, let me give you something for your help. i would buy your book, but i know most of the profits go to other people

Comment: Feel free to post more questions if you run into any issues and we'll try to help you. If you are on LinkedIn please send me invite and we can connect over there